# Stenciljs E2E Testing: how to find a child of a child in the Shadow Dom

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, stenciljs

I have components arranged like so:

```
app-home
  shadow-root
    component1
      shadow-root
        div id=div1
```

In other words both my app-home and component1 have shadow doms.

I can find component1 easily in Stenciljs E2E Tests like so:

```
const page = await newE2EPage();
await page.setContent('<app-home></app-home>');
const component1 = await page.find('app-home >>> component1');
```

But, whatever I've tried I cannot get #div1 inside component1.  It's important that I get back an E2EElement so I can use its methods such as click which trigger changes in the page.

Here's what I've tried:

1. `page.find('app-home >>> component1 >>> #div1')`

   Returns null
2. `component1.find(':host >>> #div1')` or `component1.find(':root >>> #div1')` or `component1.find('>>> #div1')` or `component1.find('#div1')` or `component1.find('component1 >>> #div1')`

   Returns null
3. `component1.shadowRoot.querySelector('#div1')`

   This method gets an element but clicking on it or dispatching an event to it has
   no effect on app-root or component1 in the page.

Any suggestions then on how to find a child of a child when both elements have shadowDOMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: I'm assuming that `component1` is in reality a valid custom element tag name (containing a dash).*

---

```js
page.find('app-home >>> component1 >>> #div1')
```

Using the `>>>` multiple times is currently not possible (see [source](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/264c0c541a3835875a519b56cae04939611000c9/src/testing/puppeteer/puppeteer-element.ts#L686-L689)). `>>>` is not an official CSS selector, so its implementation is entirely up to Stencil.js.

---

```js
component1.find(':host >>> #div1')
```

This or your similar approaches are also not possible because calling `.find` on an `E2EElement` can only find elements that are children of that element, but not the host element itself.

---

One solution is to switch entirely into the browser context:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  // this function will run in the browser context, not
  // in the Node.js context that the test is executed in.
  const appHome = document.querySelector('app-home');
  const comp1 = appHome.shadowRoot.querySelector('component1');
  const div1 = comp1.shadowRoot.querySelector('#div1');

  div1.click();
});

await page.waitForChanges();
```

You could refactor that into a helper, however I agree that it would be good if Stencil.js provided a proper API for this. Allowing the `>>>` selector multiple times would be a nice feature. I suggest you open a feature request in the Stencil.js repository.

Comment: Thanks much for this answer.
Created issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2302